# The sum of the terms in the nth group

Tags: summation

Let the natural numbers be divided into the following groups:
$ ${1}$,${2,3,4}$,${5,6,7,8,9}$.....$
What is the sum of the terms in the $n$th group?

I know that the number of terms in nth group will be $2n-1$.
But, I am not able to get a general pattern for the terms in the nth group?
Will it be different for when $n$ is even and when it is odd?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just find the sum of numbers from 1 to the last number in the $n$th group, and then from it subtract the sum of the numbers from 1 to the last number in the $(n-1)$ th group?

That is:
$$ \frac {n^2(n^2+1)} 2 - \frac {(n-1)^2((n-1)^2 + 1)} 2 $$

Simplify as you wish.

Comment: What is the last number in the nth group?

Comment: $n^2$ is the last number as can be seen easily from the sequence

Comment: Yeah, I see it too.